# I want to calculate the ones year of birth by taking his current age,

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to calculate the ones year of birth by taking his current age, for eg his age is 30, in datetimepicker box the date should be displayed as `01/01/1982`. It should be auto calculation.

```
         int todayyears = int.Parse (DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

        int a = int.Parse (int.Parse(txt_age.Text).ToString());

        string dif = (todayyears - a).ToString();

        txt_dob.Text = dif;
```

Here `txt_age` is input value given, `txt_dob` is diaplayed the date of birth automatically after the input given in `txt_age`.

Comment: Why would you convert DateTime.Now.Year to a string and then parse it again?

Comment: and why convert txt_age.Text to int to string and to int again? :)

Comment: Why are you converting int to string then back to int ( variable "a")

Comment: @JonSkeet, this really should be a compilation error (like trying to read an unassigned location).

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Why would that possibly fail to compile? You shouldn't (and can't) expect the compiler to spot *all* dumb code. The expression `DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()` is a perfectly valid one. The call to `int.Parse` with a string argument is entirely reasonable.  If you want this to fail to compile, you should think about exactly where you would change the C# specification - what rule would you add?

Comment: @JonSkeet I saw this in so many legacy projects on I worked, I'm just tired to correct this.

Comment: well just print `"01-01-"` + (DateTime.Now.Year - parsedAge).ToString()` :)

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the given question: it's the reverse. The supposed duplicate starts with a DateTime, and tries to work out the age. This question *starts* with the age, and works out the start of the year containing their birthday.

Comment: Well the question was more to arrive at the year of birth which is available in the so marked duplicate !

Comment: @V4Vendetta: In the supposed duplicate we **start** with that year as part of the user input... so of course it's available.

Comment: @JonSkeet indeed which is not the case here, voted for reopen

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're converting *way* too many things to strings, for no reason.

If you *always* want to display January 1st, you just need:

```
// Note: use int.TryParse to avoid exceptions if the user input isn't an integer
int age = int.Parse(txt_age.Text);

DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year - age, 1, 1);

txt_dob.Text = date.ToString(); // Or use a specific format
```

Note that "dob" in "txt_dob" is inappropriate, as this isn't the user's *date of birth*, just January 1st in their *year of birth* which is very different.

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like that:

```
txt_dob.Text = DateTime.Now.AddYears(int.Parse(txt_age.Text) * -1).ToString("01/01/yyyy");
```

Comment: The OP wants to display "01/01/THE_YEAR". In your example it would display "current_day/THE_YEAR".

Comment: @V4Vendetta I would do so, you do in your way, that's why people are different :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a datetime with the given year.

So calculate the year. ( Current year - Age in Years).

```
int Age = 30; // obtain from your given field.
int YofBirth = DateTime.Now.Year - Age;

DateTime d = new DateTime(YofBirth , 1, 1);
```

Then use this Datetime d to set the field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int todayyears = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int a = int.Parse(txt_age.Text);
            string dob = new DateTime(todayyears - a, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);
txt_dob.Text=dob;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int age;
if(int.TryParse(txt_age.Text,out age))
{
    txt_dob.Text= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year-age,1,1).ToShortDateString();
}
```